# Apache2 Permissions

Tags: 16.04, permissions, apache2, sudo, lamp

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.0.4 LTS and I have LAMP installed.

I am currently at the directory `/var/www/html` and I am trying to use vi to edit index.html but it's a read-only file.

I have tried looking at the permissions: `ls -l` and it shows me this:

```
total 12
---------- 1 root root 11321 May 14 18:44 index.html
```

Hope Someone can answer this!

Comment: Have you tried changing the permission? `sudo chmod 755 index.html` ?

Comment: Yes, just did tried using vi again but dident work

Comment: `sudo -i` then `umask` what is the output? enter: `exit` then run: `sudo mv index.html bk` after that: `sudo cat bk | sudo tee index.html` then `ls -l index.html`.